# Does container need to be create upfront before adding blob?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

In Azure function I'm saving received files. Different container will be used based on tenant.

```
var location = Helper.GetLocation(tenant, uploadId, ...);
using (var outputStream = await binder.BindAsync<Stream>(new BlobAttribute(location , FileAccess.Write)))
{
    await inputStream.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
}
```

Do I need to create those containers upfront? (I'm creating some using ARM templates). My testing shows I don't have to, but I'm not sure I can rely on this. If I could count on containers being created for me I wouldn't have to modify ARM template when adding new tenant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `BindAsync<Stream>` method, according to the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/b36006c56969cbaadce95b34d37ed413728b5c1f/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Bindings/Runtime/AttributeBindingSource.cs#L46):

```
        public Task<IBinding> BindAsync<TValue>(Attribute attribute, Attribute[] additionalAttributes = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            ParameterInfo parameterInfo = new FakeParameterInfo(typeof(TValue), _memberInfo, attribute, additionalAttributes);
            BindingProviderContext bindingProviderContext =
                new BindingProviderContext(parameterInfo, bindingDataContract: null, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

            return _bindingProvider.TryCreateAsync(bindingProviderContext);
        }
```

It calls the `TryCreateAsync` method. And `TryCreateAsync` will call other overloaded methods of `TryCreateAsync`.

Eventually, it calls this overloaded method [TryCreateAsync](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/b36006c56969cbaadce95b34d37ed413728b5c1f/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage/Blobs/Listeners/BlobReceiptManager.cs#L51) in `BlobReceiptManager.cs`. And in this `TryCreateAsync` method, it will check if the container is existing or not by using `bool isContainerNotFoundException = false;`. And if the container does not exist, it will use `await blob.Container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(cancellationToken);` to create this container.

So the answer is that, if the container does not exist, the sdk will automatically create it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a Binder for that. I have a complete example of that [on GitHub](https://github.com/sebader/azure-samples-collection/blob/master/AzureFunctions/SampleFunctions/UnzipBlob.cs). Just the relevant piece:

```
// We use the first char of the input file name as a dynamic part in the container. (Note: You should check if this is a valid char for the container name)
var container = $"my-dynamic-container-{inputBlobName.Substring(0,1).ToLower()}";
var attributes = new Attribute[]
{
        new BlobAttribute($"{container}", FileAccess.ReadWrite),
        new StorageAccountAttribute("AzureWebJobsStorage")
};
var outputContainer = await binder.BindAsync<CloudBlobContainer>(attributes);
await outputContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
```

Comment: But my question is about something a bit different. I'm not making additional call to create container. I specify location of blob (with container name of course) and container is created.

Comment: Got it. I just tested this with this Function and its output binding. The "myblobcontainer" did not exist beforehand and all worked fine. the container got newly created a runtime https://github.com/sebader/azure-samples-collection/blob/master/AzureFunctions/SampleFunctions/Http2BlobFunction.cs

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to create those containers upfront? (I'm creating some using
> ARM templates). My testing shows I don't have to, but I'm not sure I
> can rely on this.

I think you can rely on this. BlobAttribute writes operation is based on `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage`. This SDK has a method named `CreateIfNotExistsAsync()`. This method will check whether there is a specific container you wanted, if there is, it will return the container object, if not, it will create a container and return the container object.

You can have a look at this source code page to check the logic:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage/Blobs

(In fact, it is not just the blob attribute, many other Azure services such as cosmos DB also have the CreateIfNotExists method, the original intention is to avoid trouble.)